# Why is my react-tooltip sometimes displaying on the parent element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, tooltip, react-simple-maps

I've made a covid related travel map here: [Where Can We Go Now](https://wherecanwegonow.com)

It's a static react JS website, billy basic with [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html).  It uses amongst other things the excellent [React Simple Maps](https://www.react-simple-maps.io/) (kudos to the creator) and [react-tooltip](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip#readme).

Expected behaviour:

Locally the tooltip works fine when tested with `npm run start`

I move my mouse over a country and the tooltip displays some relevant information approximately where my mouse is on the map.

The Problem:

. . . once published with `npm run build` sort of works but strange things happen.

Please follow link to website to observe, but in short, if the sea (i.e. an area that isn't a country - so not defined by an svg in the topojson) is clicked then the tooltip is place at the top centre of the whole map itself.

Some bits of relevant code:

Index.js (snippet):

```
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  return (
    <div><h1> Where can we go on holiday ?* </h1>
      <MapChart setTooltipContent={setContent}/>
      <ReactTooltip html={true}>{content}</ReactTooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

MapChart.js (snippet):

```
    return (
      <div>
        <p><small>*Right now in the UK: {data.headlineAdviceNow}   Last updated at {updateString}</small></p>
      <ComposableMap
        
        projectionConfig={{
          rotate: [-40, -30, 10],
          scale: 1600
        }}
        width={mapWidth}
        height={mapHeight}
        style={{ maxWidth: "100%", height: "80vh", background: "#b3b3b3", borderStyle: "solid", borderColor: "white", margin: 0.5,
        borderRadius: 20 }}
      >
        <ZoomableGroup zoom={zoom} center={center} translateExtent={[
          [0, 0],
          [mapWidth, mapHeight]
        ]} maxZoom={15} data-tip="">
        <Sphere stroke="#E4E5E6" strokeWidth={0.5} />
        <Graticule stroke="#E4E5E6" strokeWidth={0.2} />
        
        {!loading && (<Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
            {({ geographies }) =>
              geographies.map((geo) => {
                const d = data.countries.find((s) => s.country.iso_a3 === geo.properties.ISO_A3);
                return (
                  <Geography
                    key={geo.rsmKey}
                    geography={geo}
                    style={{
                      default: {
                        outline: "none",
                        stroke: "grey",
                        strokeWidth: "1",
                        strokeLinecap: "butt",
                        fill: d ? colorScale(d[attr]) : "#F5F4F6"
                      },
                      hover: {
                        outline: "none",
                        stroke: "black",
                        strokeWidth: "3",
                        strokeLinecap: "butt",
                        fill: d ? colorScale(d[attr]) : "#F5F4F6"
                      },
                      pressed: {
                        outline: "none"
                      }
                    }}
                    onMouseEnter={() => {
                      const NAME = geo.properties.NAME;
                      const travelIndex = d ? d["indexDescription"] : "Unknown";
                      //const border = d ? d["borderStatusString"] : "Unknown";
                      const returnStatus = d ? (fromCountry==="GBR" ? d["ukCategory"] : "TBC") : "Unknown";
                      const vaccinePc = d ? d.vaccineData["total_vaccinations_per_hundred"] + "%" : "NK";
                      const arrival = (() => {try{ return d["restrictionsFrom"][data["iomKeys"].indexOf(fromCountry)].split("-") } catch {return [4,""]}});
                      const arrivalLevel = rstrctLkup[arrival()[0]]["short"]
                      //const arvlRtns = arrival()[1].length===0 ? arrival()[1] : arrival()[1].split(",")
                      //var text =""
                      //var i;
                      //for (i = 0; i < arvlRtns.length; i++) {
                      //  if (data["restrictionDefs"][arvlRtns[i]]) {
                      //  if (i===0) {text="<br />Arrival Details:<br />"}
                      //  text += data["restrictionDefs"][arvlRtns[i]] + "<br>";
                      //}}
                      
                      setTooltipContent(`<b>${NAME.toUpperCase()}:</b> ${travelIndex}<br /><p style="text-align: left"><b>RISK FACTORS</b><br />Vaccinated: ${vaccinePc}<br /><br /><b>CURRENT RESTRICTIONS</b><br />Entry: ${arrivalLevel}<br />Return: ${returnStatus}</p>`);
                    }}
                    onMouseLeave={() => {
                      setTooltipContent("");
                    }}
                  />
                );
              })
            }
          </Geographies>
        )}
        </ZoomableGroup>
      </ComposableMap>
      </div>
    );
  };  

export default memo(MapChart);
```

What I've tried:

Variations of setting tooltip position, and moving where and what `data-tip=""` is. Also, banging head on wall.

Answer (score 0):

I was inaccurate in my question, so didn't provide relevant details that was the source of the problem.

I publish with github actions and this was the fix:

```
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

The frozen lockfile was the key to make sure I was using the exact versions of relevant packages as I had been testing locally.  I'd erroneously suggested I was using npm.